# Is there a group of modules that would allow to assign new permissions to users basing on the votes they receive for their comments, or posts?

Tags: 7

If I would implement something similar to the reputation system implemented in the Stack Exchange sites, which modules should I install on my Drupal site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) to allow users to collect points for things they do. See [Userpoints Nodes and Comments](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_nc) for granting points when users post comments or nodes.

Then, [Userpoints Contrib](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) contains both modules to integrate with Voting (not all modules which are part of the 7.x-1.x-dev release have been ported to Drupal 7 yet) and the ability to assign roles to a user when he has a certain amount of points. Note that Userpoints Contrib 6.x is in a rather bad shape, most modules in there are really buggy. However, we worked hard on the first round of module upgrades to 7.x in this issue: http://drupal.org/node/869770 and have released the first few modules which are well tested and should be quite stable.

Answer (score 2):

The [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module would be your best bet, but it would need integrating with a voting system.

Although still in development, the [Voting Rules](http://drupal.org/project/voting_rules) module seems to be what you are looking for. Here is [an issue](http://drupal.org/node/971394) for it to be integrated with the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi).

Comment: The userpoints looks like a better fit; although you could probably achieve the same with the voting rules / API I'd probably start with userpoints.

Comment: @RichardHarrison I partially agree ... I think you also need to add "Voting API" and "Rules" as additional ingredients

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's perfectly possible to do what you're asking for. Here is a summary of how to do so (and only using popular modules with stable releases ...):

- Use User Points to implement a reputation system.
- Transform votes in User points.
- Assign a new role if sufficient User Points.
- Remove role if insufficient User Points.

Read on for more details about each of these steps.

#### Step 1 - Use User Points to implement a reputation system

The typical solution to implement a reputation system in a Drupal site, is to use the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module, combined with using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to grant some amount of points, e.g. based on received votes.

#### Step 2 - Transform votes in User points

Anything about voting in Drupal boils down to (= depends on) using the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) module. And using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), it is possible to transform votes (up or down) towards User Points, as detailed in my answer to "[How to use Rules to transform upvotes and downvotes towards User Points?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41538/how-to-use-rules-to-transform-upvotes-and-downvotes-towards-user-points/206161#206161)".

#### Step 3 - Assign a new role if sufficient User Points

You can use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) also to assign a new role (grant permissions) to a user as soon as they have accumulated a predefined number of User Points. As an example, have a look at this Rules example (in Rules export format):

```
{ "rules_grant_new_role" : {
    "LABEL" : "Grant a new role",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "userpoints_rules", "rules", "rules_conditional" ],
    "ON" : { "userpoints_event_points_awarded_after" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "site:current-user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "total_points" : "Number of points in all categories together" } }
        }
      },
      { "CONDITIONAL" : [
          {
            "IF" : { "NOT data_is" : { "data" : [ "total-points" ], "op" : "\u003C", "value" : "11" } },
            "DO" : [
              { "user_add_role" : {
                  "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
                  "roles" : { "value" : { "5" : "5" } }
                }
              },
              { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You have at least 11 points (actually you have [total-points:value] points ...)." } }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The above rule does retrieve, as the very first Rules Action (not Rules Condition) the current amount of User Points of a user. If the amount is at least 11, it will show an appropriate message about that and it will grant the role with role id = `5` (adapt this role id and/or amount of user points needed to fit your needs).

In this example I'm using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, though you could also rework the Rules Action to performing a Rules Component (in which you add the appropriate Rules Conditions), so that you don't need this extra module.

[image]

Just in case you don't realize: the clue to make this rule work is the very first Rules Action "***Load user points of a user***". That's the alternative (work around?) for something like a missing Rules Condition to "check the current user points for a user".

#### Step 4 - Remove role if insufficient User Points

Using a variation of the rule shown in step 3, you can also remove such role again if something happens so that the amount of user points is no longer sufficient. I assume anybody can tweak the rule in step 3 for this case also (if not [click here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)).

#### Note: Use the Answers module as an example

To actually implement such reputation system, the number and types of Rules you'll need is not just "a couple of them". You'll need to take into consideration upvoting, downvoting, un-upvoting, un-dowvoting, disallow votes from the author, etc. To avoid re-inventing the wheel, have a look at the various rules included with the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) for a lot of inspiration about this.

Comment: How do you trigger the action?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer : which "acton" do you mean?

Comment: sorry the rule, how do you trigger the rule? and forget it, I come from read ***"Load user points of a user"*** ;-)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I "*think*" you mean you understood it now (that it is clear anyway). If that is still not the case, please let me know ...

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer **this is the actual trigger:** `"ON" : { "userpoints_event_points_awarded_after" : [] },` which is called `User was awarded points` in the UI.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer see updated answer, hope that clarifies things `:)`