# How to use Rules to transform upvotes and downvotes towards User Points?

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints, rating

I know that there is the [Userpoints Karma](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_karma) module, and this is only updated to Drupal 6 version.

Are there any techniques for transforming votes towards User Points? Or can you point me in the direction of reference for creating a custom module for this purpose?

**Note**: The votingpoints module is not available for Drupal 7, so I was looking into using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to grant points to the creator of a node, when a user votes on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in these pages you can find what you need.

[User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) This is a module

[User Points Contributed modules](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib) more modules!

Choose the one that fits in your website.

Comment: thanks, that is useful, but the votingpoints module is not available for drupal 7, so I was looking into using rules to grant points to the creator of a node, when a user votes on it.

Comment: User points is available for drupal 7. Use it with the rules.

Comment: okay I will give that another go. Have you used rules before in this context?

Comment: this will be very helpful for me: http://s1l.org/userpoints-voting-rules

Comment: there is a good tutorial for Rules, http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-rules ,it's in different episodes covering all the area of the module.

Answer (score 1):

## Question refinement

The [Userpoints Karma](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_karma) module is indeed not available for D7. The purpose of this module was like so (from its project page):

> Userpoints Karma integrates the [Vote Up/Down](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module with the [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module to provide a node/comment rating karma system.
>
> The module allows a voter using the vote/up down widget to add or subtract points to the author of a given node or comment, thereby awarding or punishing the author for what they wrote. The number of points is configurable by the site's admin. Also, the node types are configurable, so that is shown on nodes or comments of a certain type, and not others.
>
> The module can notify users when they login with a total of points gained/lost due to others voting up their nodes or comments.

And this module depends on the [Vote Up/Down](https://www.drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module (which only has an alfa1 version for D7).

With all this in mind, for D7, I would recommend you to go for a combination of these alternative, and often used modules to achieve the same goal (= add (or subtract) user points when some node is voted up (or down)):

- [Voting API](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi).
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Voting Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/voting_rules) (attention: alfa version only).
- [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) (still ... of course).

It's also the approach used in the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it), i.e. within its submodule "Answers Userpoints". If you agree, read on ...

## Required Rules

To handle all variations of voting, you need 4 rules (only!), which cover these 4 cases:

- a node is upvoted.
- an upvote for a node is canceled (= no longer upvoted).
- a node is downvoted.
- a downvote for a node is canceled (= no longer downvoted).

Below are the required rules, for each of these cases (use the Rules UI to import them in your own site, after you enabled the required modules mentioned above). These rules are enhanced versions of the rules included in the 7.x-4.0-rc2 version of [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) (and are expected to be committed to its dev version also). They use a content type with machine name `answers_question` (adapt this name to fit your own machine name).

#### Upvote a node

The rule below will grant +5 user points for an upvote (to the author of the node):

```
{ "rules_voteup_question" : {
    "LABEL" : "voteup_question",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_insert_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "5",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Receive upvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionUpvoteReceived",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Cancel the upvote a node

The rule below will grant -5 (= remove +5) user points for a cancelled upvote (to the author of the node):

```
{ "rules_voteup_question_cancel" : {
    "LABEL" : "voteup_question_cancel",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_delete_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "-5",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Unupvote [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionUpvoteCancelled",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Downvote a node

The rule below will subtract -2 (grant -2) user points for a downvote (to the author of the node) ... **AND** also -1 user point for the voter:

```
{ "rules_votedown_question" : {
    "LABEL" : "votedown_question",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_insert_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "-1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "-2",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Receive downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteReceived",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "-1",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Issue downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteIssued",
          "reference" : "From uid=[node:author:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Cancel the downvote a node

The rule below will grant +2 (= remove -2) user points for a cancelled downvote (to the author of the node) ... **AND** also +1 user point for the voter:

```
{ "rules_votedown_question_cancel" : {
    "LABEL" : "votedown_question_cancel",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "answers" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "voting_rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "voting_rules_delete_node" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "answers_question" : "answers_question" } }
        }
      },
      { "voting_rules_condition_check_vote_value" : { "vote" : [ "vote" ], "value" : "-1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "node:author" ],
          "points" : "2",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Cancel downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteCancelled",
          "reference" : "By uid=[vote:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "vote:user" ],
          "points" : "1",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Withdraw downvote to [node:type-name] \u0022[node:title]\u0022",
          "operation" : "QuestionDownvoteWithdrawn",
          "reference" : "From uid=[node:author:uid], for [node:type-name] to q=\u003Ca href=\u0022\/node\/[node:nid]\u0022\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/a\u003E",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Reporting

Even though it may not be obvious from just browsing the (4) exported rules above, note the `description`, `operation` and `reference` used in each of the User Point transactions.

After you enabled the above rules and generated some (test) data with them (by voting on the nodes they relate to), go have a look at the typical [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) reports.

Here is an example of how it could look like:

```
Points Date                     Reason                          Status      Actions
   5   Fri, 04/01/2016 - 16:30  Receive upvote to Question ...  Approved   view edit
  -5   Fri, 04/01/2016 - 16:29  Unupvote Question "How to i...  Approved   view edit
   2   Mon, 03/28/2016 - 14:41  addPoints                       Approved   view edit
  -2   Mon, 03/28/2016 - 14:40  removePoints                    Approved   view edit
  10   Thu, 03/17/2016 - 13:52  Upvote Answer to "What are ...  Approved   view edit
   5   Tue, 03/15/2016 - 11:30  Upvote Question "How to imp...  Approved   view edit
  -5   Tue, 03/15/2016 - 11:27  Voting Corrected                Approved   view edit
```